# probleme Date vs Datetime in symfony

Tags: symfony, date

I want to send a json to my api like this :

```
{
    "civility": "Mr",                   
    "lastname": "toto",             
    "firstname": "titi",                
    "email": "mon@email.com",   
    "birthday_date": "1970-01-01"
}
```

But I have this response:

```
{"code":400,"message":"Invalid datetime \"1970-01-01\", expected format Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP."}
```

My validation.yml:

```
    birthdayDate:
        - Date: ~
```

My entity:

```
/**
 * @var date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthdayDate", type="date")
 * 
 */
private $birthdayDate;
```

The solution I've found is to format the datetime:

```
$birthday_date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP')
```

But if it's possible I'd prefer to send with the format ('y-m-d').

Comment: Removed my answer as it was build upon wrong assumptions. :-)

Comment: That is... weird... I reviewed the source code of `DateValidator` and I cannot spot the reference to that format. Which version of `Symfony` is that?

Comment: Can you please share the `controller` where you `serialize` the data.

Comment: Hi ! my version is symfony 3.3

Comment: PS : i'm using JMSSerializer